# Get first item of a non-typed IEnumeration

Tags: vb.net, generics

```
Public Function MLAKeys() As IEnumerable
    Return Tables(dbTblMLAs).pRow.Keys
End Function
```

pRow is a Dictionary. I am returning this as a non-typed enumerable so that it will export to COM. The project using .NET3. It does not have Linq.

How can I get the first row? Looking over the various solutions here, it seems you get the enumerator, movenext and getcurrent. Well...

```
 Dim K As IEnumerator = DP.MLAKeys.GetEnumerator
```

fails because it won't let you declare IEnumerator without a type. I tried adding (of Object) but then the types are different and I can't assign the function output.

Anyone know the trick here?

Comment: You should be able to use `IEnumerator` without a type. Are you getting a compilation error or a runtime exception? what is the message for the error/exception?

Comment: It is at compile time. It simply turns the line red and says that it is invalid without a (of T) clause.

Comment: I tried similar code on my machine and it is working. Can you provide a more complete code?